# react native passing array in cloneWithRows

Tags: android, listview, react-native, reactjs

I want to pass an array to the cloneWithRows method.
below is the code

```
export default class FirstReactNativeApp extends Component {

          constructor() {
            super();
            const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

          this.state = {
            modalVisible: false,
            todoText:'',
            todoListArray:['foo 1','foo 2'],
           dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.todoListArray)

          };
        }
```

This is the Listview

```
<ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{JSON.stringify(rowData)</Text>}
/>
```

I'm getting the error
**undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this.state.todoListArray')**

I'm not able to resolve this.Please guide me!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

  this.state = {
    modalVisible: false,
    todoText:'',
    todoListArray:['foo 1','foo 2'],
  };
}
```

---

```
<ListView
        dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.todoListArray)}
        renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{JSON.stringify(rowData)</Text>}
/>
```

Comment: While using this its still gave the error
 undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this.ds.cloneWithRows')

Comment: that's because you didn't change `const ds` to `this.ds`

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the `state` object before setting it. so it returns `undefined`. Try like this

```
export default class FirstReactNativeApp extends Component {

      constructor() {
        super();
        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

      this.state = {
        modalVisible: false,
        todoText:'',
        todoListArray:['foo 1','foo 2'],
       dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['foo 1','foo 2'])

      };
  }
```

Then later when `todoListArray` content changes, you can set it to `dataSource` as

```
this.setState({
                dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.todoListArray),
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer given by vinayr gave me a clue.

```
      this.state = {
        modalVisible: false,
        todoText:'',
        todoListArray:['foo 1','foo 2'],
        dataSource: ds

      };
```

and then in the List View

```
<ListView
  dataSource= {this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.todoListArray)}
  renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>} />
```

It works!

Thanks